# Reading file from remote linux server in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am building transformation in Penthao.My requirment is to read data from an `xlxs` file present on the remote Linux server and then write that data to a Database table.

Could you please explain how this can be done...?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share?

Comment: hi Fred,Thank You for the quick reply .Could you please suggest is it possible to read the data of a xlxs file presented on remote linux server using pentaho .

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the linux remote path directly in the File/Directory path.

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue !!! :)

Comment: can you try doing SFTP the file ??... just thinking of some alternte soln.